# ReactJS: Map array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to map array of objects `[{thing: '', quantity: ''}]` with ReactJS and this is the code i use for it (and it does not work).

**EDIT** this is the original code

```
<ul>
   {this.state.ingredients.map(({i,q},k)=>{           
       return ( 
          <div key={k}>
             <li>{i} - {q}</li><br/>
          </div>
       )
    })}  
</ul>
```

what is the reason?

Comment: what do you mean by "do not work"? do you have any error message?

Comment: No, it just does not maps

Comment: Invalid syntax probably. `.map({t,q},k)` this is not valid destructuring syntax. You probably want `.map(({t,q},k)=>`, with the extra `(` to signify the function.

Comment: @Shilly I did not copied this code from my workspace i wrote down it here and it is just typo

Comment: i mean code is same but i changed variable names and maybe i deleted ( accidentally

Comment: @iLiA On a separate note you don't need to add a key to the `<li />` element, just on the outer `<div />`. The `<li />` is contained within the div so React can keep track of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the properties to your map. When destructuring objects, you need to provide the exact keys.

for example, doing the following returns undefined, since obj doesn't have the given props. [Object_destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

```js
const obj = {a: 'a', b: 'b'}

const { c, d} = obj;

console.log(c, d);
```

```
{this.state.things.map(({ thing, quantity }, k) => {
  return (
    <div key={k}>
      <li key={k}>{thing} - {quantity}</li><br />
    </div>
  )
})}
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      things: [{ thing: 'Thing ', quantity: 23 }],
    };
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.things.map(({ thing, quantity }, k) => {
          return (
            <div key={k}>
              <li key={k}>{thing} - {quantity}</li><br />
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Comment: isn't `thing` and `quantity` arguments of callback function?

Comment: `(({ thing,quantity }, k)` - you're missing a open bracket.

Comment: @JuniusL. demo works but i can not see differnece between your and my code

Comment: in your code, you are using keys `t` and `q` which don't exists in the object.

Comment: Oh, i literally forgot about destructing

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for something like this, you are not destructuring correctly.

```js
const obj = {thing:'something',quantity:1};
const arr = [obj];
{
arr.map(({ thing, quantity }, index) => {
    return ( 
        <div key={index}>
           <li>{thing} - {quantity}</li><br/>
        </div>
    )
})}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```